# Скрыть доступ к прямым ссылкам

Tags: php, веб-программирование, nginx, hosting, forum

Имеется файловый хостинг внутри закрытой локальной сети. Многие пользователи загружают контент (фото, видео, файлы), затем берут ссылку на файл и вставляют на форум.

Хостинг и форум находятся на одной виртуальной машине. Как сделать так, чтобы на странице темы форума изображение, к примеру, отображалось, а по прямой ссылке доступ к изображению был закрыт?

Понимаю, что можно реализовать запрос со стороны форума к хостинг серверу, но для этого придется немного модернизировать сам форум (использовать curl). Возможно, есть какие-то более элегантные решения?

Comment: Для начала надо ответить для себя на вопрос: чем отличается запрос браузера к картинке размещенной на странице от запроса в адресной строке. Так вот - они отличатся могут только наличием заголовка Referer, указывающего на страницу форма. Можно попробовать в nginx проверять наличие этого заголовка и его корректность. Но заголовок разумеется легко подделать, так что защитится физически возможно только от передачи ссылки кому нибудь, кто ее в браузере попытается открыть, не более. Если этого не достаточно, то придется делать временные ссылки, которые быстро перестают работать

Comment: Да, этого достаточно для изображений и файлов. А как быть с видео?

Comment: На счет видео не представляю. Как я наблюдал ставят встроенные видео-плееры, которые тянут по зашитым в них алгоритмам и видео при этом бьют на множество отдельных кусочков. Ну и дальше либо защищают так же по каким нибудь заголовкам или дают псевдослучайные имена, которые умеет генерить плеер

Comment: И все-таки, склоняюсь к curl. Видео таким образом воспроизводится, но пока с перемоткой проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Лучшим вариантом решения оказалось использование заголовка x-accel-redirect в nginx.
https://www.opennet.ru/base/net/nginx_x_accel_redirect.txt.html