# django + nginx - файлы доступные только если django "разрешает"

Tags: django, nginx

Как настроить `nginx`, чтобы он отдавал файлы только если код на `django` предоставил ссылку?

То есть на `django` есть `view`, которая принимает, например, `id` записи модели с файлом, а затем происходит редирект на файл, после чего `nginx` отдает файл. Прямой доступ к файлу должен быть запрещен.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416754/190728 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431630/190728 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1227195/190728

Comment: @AlexeyTen эх, отвязать бы это всё от конкретного языка/фреймворка...

Comment: Создать «фейковый» вопрос и ответ? =)

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.